# A possible easy proof of Borel determinacy?

Tags: solution-verification, descriptive-set-theory, infinite-games

I was initially trying to prove determinacy of $\mathbf{\Sigma}^0_2$ games, but surprisingly the proof I came up with seems to generalise all the way to Borel determinacy. Obviously this sounds a little too good to be true, but it still appears correct to me after double-checking many times. Perhaps someone can help me spot mistakes which I might have overlooked?

The proof:

**Lemma.** Suppose all $\mathbf{\Pi}^0_\alpha$ games are determined. Let $G(T,A)$ be such a game, and suppose $II$ has a winning strategy. If $W_{II}$ is $II$'s canonical quasistrategy, and $s = \langle x_1,\ldots,x_{2k}\rangle$ is a branch such that $\langle x_1,\ldots,x_{2k-1}\rangle\in W_{II}$ but $s\notin W_{II}$, then $I$ has a winning strategy in the game $G(T_s,A\cap N_s)$.

*Proof.* The subgame $G(T_s,A\cap N_s)$ is also $\mathbf{\Pi}^0_\alpha$ and hence determined. So if $I$ doesn't have a winning strategy, then $II$ does. But then this implies that the $W_{II}$ can be extended to a larger (winning) quasistrategy containing the winning strategy from the branch $s$, and we have $s\in W_{II}$ which is a contradiction. $\square$

Let $G=G(T,A)$ be a $\mathbf{\Sigma}^0_\alpha$ game, where $A=\bigcup_n A_n$ and each $A_n$ is $\mathbf{\Pi}^0_{\gamma_n}$ with $\gamma_n<\alpha$. By induction, the games $G_n=G(T,A_n)$ are determined. If $I$ has a winning strategy for at least one of the $G_n$'s, then this is also a winning strategy for $G$.

Otherwise, $II$ has a canonical quasistrategy $(W_{II})_n$ for each $G_n$. Let $W$ be the intersection of these quasistrategies (when viewed as sets of branches).

**Case 1.** If $W$ contains a strategy, then this is automatically a winning strategy for $II$ in $G$.

**Case 2.** Otherwise, $W$ contains what I call *conflicting* branches: a branch $s=\langle x_1,\ldots,x_{2k-1}\rangle$ is conflicting if

1. $s\in W$.
2. For all $x_{2k}$ satisfying $s\frown x_{2k}\in T$, there is some $n$ such that $s\frown x_{2k} \notin (W_{II})_n$.

If $s$ is conflicting, then regardless of $II$'s next move $x_{2k}$, by the lemma $I$ always has a winning strategy in some $G_n$ (hence $G$) starting from $s\frown x_{2k}$. Furthermore, $I$ has a strategy that always leads to *some* conflicting branch (otherwise $II$'s counter-strategy that avoids all conflicting branches is itself a substrategy of $W$, which is a contradiction). Therefore, $I$ has a winning strategy in $G$ overall.

Lastly, determinacy of $\mathbf{\Sigma}^0_\alpha$ games implies determinacy of $\mathbf{\Pi}^0_\alpha$ games, completing the inductive step.

Comment: I don't see how it makes sense to see a quasistrategy as a set of branches. For example $II$ might have strategies from every point on, but you loose all information about these strategies if you just look at the tree (if I even understand correctly what you mean by the corresponding tree). In particular your case 1 just looks wrong.

Comment: A quasistrategy (for $II$) can be thought of as a set of branches $\sigma\subset T$ such if $s\in\sigma$ has odd length then $s\frown x \in\sigma$ for some $x$, and if $s\in\sigma$ has even length then $s\frown x \in\sigma$ for all $x$. Thus it seems reasonable to talk about an intersection of quasistrategies, and whether or not the intersection contains some strategy as a subset.

Comment: If the intersection contains some strategy, then by following this strategy, $II$ is by definition following a winning strategy for every $G_n$ simultaneously.

Comment: @What I mean is that this tree in general gives you no information about a strategy at all. Especially considering your Lemma. The way you define it (by the Lemma), if $II$ has a strategy everywhere, the tree is just $T$ itself. This might even be the case for every $G_n$ and the intersection is just $T$ again. But this doesn't give you a winning strategy for $II$ (even if there is some strategy).

Comment: On a side note, it is known that Borel determinacy needs applications of the power set axiom and the replacement scheme, unless ZFC is inconsistent.

Comment: Ah I see the issue now. So am I right to say that the canonical quasistrategy is not necessarily a winning quasistrategy?

Answer (score 1):

*This has been answered in the comments; I'm posting to move this off the unanswered queue, and have made this CW to avoid reputation gain.*

---

The problem with your argument, as Jonathan observed above, is that the "canonical quasistrategies" are actually extremely **weak** objects. Take for example the game on $\{0,1\}$ where player $II$ wins as long as they *ever* play a "$1$." Obviously every state is a winning state for player $II$, so the canonical quasistrategy in this case is ... "do whatever you want." But there are clearly **plays consistent with this quasistrategy** according to which player $II$ loses.

Of course the above nonsense can't happen if the payoff set is closed - this is why closed determinacy is so easy to prove! This indicates a purely topological difficulty in proving determinacy: the set of plays consistent with a given quasistrategy will always be closed, so essentially we need all of our winnable payoff sets to have perfect subsets. Note that it's already not obvious that every *Borel* set has a perfect subset (or has complement with a perfect subset); this can be proved using closed determinacy + unfolding (see Kechris' book), but is definitely nontrivial.

The fix, *very* broadly speaking, is to look at quasistrategies *with promises*, which prevent the sort of "silly-loss-by-infinite-delay" - as well as its less-silly versions - that cropped up above. This ultimately takes the form of converting an arbitrary rank Borel game on $\mathbb{N}$ or similar into a closed game on a much more complicated set. Interestingly, this is a bit more than we need for determinacy - it's a stronger property called "unravelability," whose [exact extent seems much more mysterious](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370283/what-sets-can-be-unraveled).